# How does a negative trigger close the latch in triac?

Tags: triac

When anode to cathode voltage is positive, I get that the left latch will be closed if positive voltage is applied at gate.

However when anode to cathode voltage is negative, I don't get how the right latch will be closed if *negative* voltage is applied at the gate.

I feel *positive* voltage at gate must close the latch in second case too. Because no matter how the diode is oriented positive at P side forward biases a diode. But my textbook says the opposite.  Highly appreciate any help. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: That circuit (a) is not a good representation of a triac.

Comment: Download some triac datasheet and look for quadrants, you'll get some basic idea.